# Single Row Shows Insight RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview and it shows just single records instead of two records.  I have searched many post on google and found to modify height of listview items from "match_parent " To "Wrap_Content" hence I did the same but still it shows single records.

Activity Mumbai_Male

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MumbaiMale">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/myImg"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/age"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/education"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomeAdapter is:

```
package com.maheshwaghela.mahesh.rukhivivah;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private MumbaiMale.IconData[] data;

public CustomAdapter (MumbaiMale.IconData[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mumbai_male, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(data[position].getPname());
    holder.age.setText(data[position].getPage());
    holder.education.setText(data[position].getPedu());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(data[position].getImgId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView age; public TextView education;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
        this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        this.age=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        this.education=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.education);
      }
   }

}
```

Mumbai_Male.Java

```
package com.maheshwaghela.mahesh.rukhivivah;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;


public class MumbaiMale extends  AppCompatActivity {



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mumbai_male);


    IconData[] data = new IconData[] {
            new IconData("Name:- Mahesh K. Waghela","Age:-45","Education:-B.com", R.drawable.dilip333),
            new IconData ("Name:- Sunil K. Waghela","Age:-33","Education:-S.S.C.",R.drawable.hiteshhh)

    };

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(data);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



}

public class IconData {
    private String pname;
    private String page;
    private String pedu;
    private int imgId;

    public IconData(String name, String age, String edu, int imgId) {
        this.pname = name;
        this.page= age;
        this.pedu= edu;
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }

    public String getPname()
    {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String name)
    {
        this.pname = name;
    }


    public String getPage()
    {
        return  page;
    }

    public void setPage(String age)
    {
        this.page=age;
    }


    public String getPedu()
    {
        return pedu;
    }

    public void setMyPedu(String edu)
    {
        this.pedu=edu;
    }


    public int getImgId()
    {
        return imgId;
    }

    public void setImgId(int imgId)
    {
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
}
```

}

Where I am wrong don't know but it shows single records instead of two records.

Comment: @Mike M. I have seperated as you suggested now and it shows two records but there are hugh gap between records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current code, your `RecyclerView` will display both record for both `wrap_content` and `match_parent`. You can see second record if you will scroll your list.

Also You are getting this type of wired output because your are using the same layout as a Activity Layout and Adapter's item layout. So adapter will bind image, name etc.. but it will also display a blank `RecyclerView` for each row.

So the solution is just keep your `RecyclerView` inside `activity_mumbai_male.xml` and create new xml file for your `RecyclerView` item and inflate that layout xml file inside your adapter. Your issue will be fixed.

Please check below corrected code.

> activity_mumbai_male.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MumbaiMale">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImg"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/education"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Replace your code with my below code in CustomAdapter.xml

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and two records shows but there are hugh gap between records

Comment: The same code i have added in my project.Output: http://prntscr.com/nhj1gv. I think you will have set height "match_parent" in your item_list.xml code root layout. Check: http://prntscr.com/nhj2ln

Comment: there are constrainlayout height has "match_parent" and I have changed it to "wrap_content now it works fine but are no gap between records I want to put some minor gap between two records

Comment: I don't think you need to change constrainlayout height. If you will change item_list.xml > root layout height as wrap_content then it will work fine. Because the same above code i have executed in my android studio.

Comment: I have taken attached screenshot from my device: https://prnt.sc/nhj1gv

Answer (score 0):

You are using RecyclerView, but I could not found your xml regarding Row, you have set text to the Simple Single TextView Which you have provide in your activity_mumbai.xml, To you recyclerview you need to create another xml, which is counted as a row, means single item of your RecyclerView, and Print your xml data in that view.

row_item_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/myImg"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/age"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/education"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

and Change SetContentView in your **custom adapter** with this new xml.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_view, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Its shows two records but hugh gap between the two records

Comment: @user2741987 You should try this step by step information for [Working With RecyclerView Android](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/). Do not forget to mark answer as correct, if you found issue of your solution.

Comment: Its height issue in ConstraintLayout from "match_parent" to wrap_content

Comment: Okay, that's great, finally you got the answer. Now Do not forget to **mark answer as correct** , if you found issue of your solution